# Auditing a .net application using sql

Tags: mysql, .net, database, security, audit

What would be the answer for how do you audit .net application for security using Sql server database?

I said by using triggers. But I don’t know the answer. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you just have a look at [SQLShack page] (https://www.sqlshack.com/various-techniques-to-audit-sql-server-databases/)

They list out and explain some of the auditing techniques using SQL server databases.